# 404 Error on CodeIgniter with WAMP and URL ReWrite

Tags: php, url-rewriting, wamp, codeigniter-2

I am running Win 8 64x with WAMP. I have a CodeIgniter project (v2.13), and I've followed the documentation and online tutorials on how to get the `/index.php/` out of the URLs so that my URLs look like so `http://127.0.0.1/petclub/home/index`.

However it isn't working. I get the a 404 Error and the message on the page is:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /petclub/index.php/home/index was not found on this server.
```

Here is what I currently have in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /petclub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried all suggestions, and none of them seem to be working for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a controller called home?

Do you have a method in your home controller called index?

You will need both of these for that to work